# Extending from Angular Material Components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-material

In my angular project I want to extend/inherit from angular material components instead of using material component itself(e.g. not mat-checkbox but just a regular checkbox which extends mat-checkbox). In this way i want to inherit all properties and methods from mat checkbox. Unfortunately I'm facing with a compilation error. Bellow you can find the link for stackblitz where you can take a look on the project and the error itself

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-hulqfu?file=app%2Fcheckbox%2Fcheckbox.component.ts

Please take a look at the error in the console.

Comment: Hi, as I can see, you are new in angular framework, are you? First, your stackblitz project is built badly, you don't have a principal module (AppModule). All components must be declared in a core or feature module. Second, I am not sure what you want to perform, if you want to customize the checkbox material component you can create a wrapper component and customize it.

Comment: True, the reason for the message is that Angular's app.module must know about the component.  The project was not created using ng new ProjectName.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, first of all @ChristianGálvez I'm not new in Angular world and the stackblitz is just to show what we need to do in our local environment all declarations are done and appModule is updated accordingly, John Peters  we already tried that approach but now we trying to figure out if we can directly extend from material components

Comment: @ChristianGálvez I have updated the stackblitz now you can see the error. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to inherit from any Material component you need to first, as obvious it may seem, install and add the library to the project:
`https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started`.

Afterwards, I would recommend you to verify whether everything has been set correctly by trying to use the MatCheckbox in the AppComponent (or any already declared component). Remember to previously add the MatCheckboxModule to the AppModule (or its corresponding module) in the imports section.

Once you don't have any kind of errors, then you can create a component which extends from the respective Material component. Don't forget to import it in the declarations section.

That should work since it is just Typescript inheritance, although I'm not sure what is exactly what you're looking to accomplish and whether inheritance is the best way to approach it.